# While preparing a gantt chart, which things we should take care?

Tags: documentation, estimation

In software developement project..
While preparing a gantt chart, which things we should take care?

Comment: could you give some additional info, the sentence is not really clear/correct

Comment: Do you want to make a Gantt Chart software, or are you trying to make a Gantt Chart for your software project?

Answer (score 2):

A very vague question, kind of like "What is the meaning of life?".

Things that occur to me:

- Knowing what you will build

  2. the order in which things have to be build,
  3. resources required,
  4. when things have to be finished,
  5. who will have to check the build items,
  6. when are people and resources available.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several tasks which are proving difficult to estimate then try to have them run in parallel.  That way you reduce the overall risk should one or more of them overrun.

Answer (score 1):

1. The WBS 100% rule (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure#The_100.25_rule))
2. Where relevant, use abstract time units in the chart and scale to meet a fixed release date.
3. Don't overuse. Use it for what it's good for. For example, avoid showing too many dependencies: Draw out a separate dependency tree